# File upload:: Empty Folder using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to upload an empty folder using third party libraries like jquery.fileupload.js, jquery.min.js.
In onDrop function::
this._getDroppedFiles(dataTransfer)**.always(function (files)**
in dataTransfer i'm getting all the values like filetypes, files, etc but when it goes to always method my other files coming but **empty folder are not** there.

I have searched a lot, Didn't find any solution.
If there's a way please let me know

Regards

Comment: For any meaningful help, you need to provide minimal code (both client and server sides) that reproduces the error, and error messages. BTW, why are you trying to “upload” empty folders? You can just create a folder with server side code.

Comment: I was trying something different so that user can upload a folder structure.

Comment: What are you using server side? There is a chance the server side code is trying to upload to a temp folder and lacks the permission to create subfolders there.

Answer (score -1):

Browsers are historically poor upload managers especially when it comes to folders. There probably isn't a great solution you'll find for uploading empty folders. Behavior might also vary depending on the browser you are using.

But as far as getting empty folders via drag/drop - there shouldn't be any problem there. What happens when you try a different browser?